# Array saving entire input file to one index? C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

this might look familiar, but am having different problems come up, so I'm trying to ask a different question. My assignment is to read in a file like so:

```
AACTGGTGCAGATACTGTTGA
3
AACTGGTGCAGATACTGCAGA
CAGTTTAGAG
CATCATCATCATCATCATCAT
```

The first line is the original line I will testing the following ones against, with the second line giving the number of remaining lines. When I run the following code, it prints out my entire input file, but to the first index. So while I need each line to be a separate index to be able to call them, it isn't working out.

I assume I'm going wrong by having the defined `LENGTH` and `ROW` so big, but am unsure of any other way to save it line by line, especially since it is mixed (`chars` with a line of `int` in between). My problem here is also that I have no prior knowledge given of how long either the rows of "DNA" will be nor how many lines total.

For what it's worth: I was advised a few things but am still unsure how to literally implement them.
One of these was to first use `fscanf` with `%s` for the first line, then `fscanf` with `%d` for the second, and a loop of `fscanf %s` for the remaining lines. I've tried doing that, but couldn't get that to work properly either.

The second way I was given was "`fgets()` for the first line, `fscanf() + fgetc()` for the second line, and then a loop of `fgets()` for everything that remains." Again, I am unsure of how to implement this exactly.

Please and thank you!

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 125
#define ROW 125
struct dna{
    char code [LENGTH];
};

int main(){
    char filename[] = "input1.txt";
    FILE *input = fopen("input1.txt","r");

    char firstDna[LENGTH][ROW]={""};
    int n=0,i=0,j;


    makeArray(input,firstDna);
    //closing file
    fclose(input);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void makeArray(FILE *input,char firstDna[LENGTH][ROW]){
    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
       for(j =0; j < ROW; j++){
       fscanf(input,"%c",&firstDna[i][j]); 
       printf("%c", firstDna[i][j]);
       i++;
       }
    }printf("\n\n\n");
}
```

Comment: how is this supposed to work? `makeArray` reads exactly `ROW` characters per row, but the file contains rows of different lengths.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do. So far you have said you will read a line and test it against the other lines, but you haven't said what this test involved. Also, do you really have to read the whole file, or can you read one line and then test that line, and then discard the line?

Comment: You don't need an array of lines (rows) at all. You would need it if you had to work with the lines out of order. But you don't. You only need one line at a time. Read it, check it, discard it.

Comment: @MattMcNabb basically I read in the first line and set that as a "master". Then the remaining number of lines get tested against the master, one at a time, letter by letter, and assigns a score based on them matching. I could just read each of those remaining lines, but am not sure how to make sure it only reads in the lines from 2 onward, after saving the first as "master" and second as the number of remaining lines. Does that make sense?

Comment: @n.m. I definitely could do that but am having issues with the those first two lines being read, then skipping to the remaining lines. Basically, I am unsure of how to read from line 3 > onward.

Comment: "unsure of how to read from line 3" that's probably what you should ask

Comment: @n.m. thanks! I figured out where I went wrong... I realized I was assuming that every time you read in a file, it starts back at the beginning. Didn't realize it "saves" your spot. Completely brain fart causing so much un-needed stress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the first "advise" that you mentioned, fscanf with %s for the first line and fscnanf with %d for the second ...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 125
#define ROW 125
struct dna{
    char code [LENGTH];
};

void makeArray(FILE *input,char firstDna[LENGTH][ROW])
{
    int i;
    int remaining_lines;

    fscanf(input,"%s\n",firstDna[0]);
    printf("%s\n", firstDna[0]);

    //scanning the number of remaing_lines
    fscanf(input,"%d\n",&remaining_lines);

    for(i = 1; i < LENGTH && i <= remaining_lines; i++)
    {
            fscanf(input,"%s\n",firstDna[i]);
            printf("%s\n", firstDna[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    char filename[] = "input1.txt";
    FILE *input = fopen(filename,"r");

    char firstDna[LENGTH][ROW];
    makeArray(input,firstDna);
    //closing file
    fclose(input);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

hope this helps